# Button click only adds a part of the values array to the Google Sheets spreadsheet sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, addeventlistener

I am following the video from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRQvySxaCW0&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemt82hBENyneRyHnD-zORB3l&index=1

I created the web app step by step but seems like the date is only getting recorded. Code used:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  //Logger.log(e.parameter);
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page")
 }

 function userClicked(name){
   url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jWpCgCH8oziO6-JrRhP0A6BEpN00BGJb7y9bbASykT0/edit#gid=0";
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
   ws.appendRow([name, new Date()]);
   //Logger.log(name+ " clicked the button");
  }
```

**page.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Hello </h1>
<label> Name: </label> <input type = "text" id = "username">
<button id = "btn"> Click Here! </button>

<script> 
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff());

   function doStuff(){
     var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
     google.script.run.userClicked(uname);
     document.getElementById("username").value = "";
   }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you anybody point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**The error is in the line  `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff());`**

- Using the function name with brackets `doStuff()` will make the function execute too directly on page load rather than on event listener.
- To execute the funciton only on event listener, please use the syntax without brackets - `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);`

**References:**

- [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)
- [Calling functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

**Note:**

- It is good practice to implement logs (e.g. console.log(uname)`0 at different strategic parts of your code to troubleshoot where the execution flow goes wrong.